# Android Material Design working with Tabs(TabLayout) in XML

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am trying to use `TabLayout` in android application.I checked various resources but not able to figure out how can I create tabs configured in **XML only**.
 I know how to add tabs programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this at the moment. I would tell you to check [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) and see that `TabLayout` has no xml attributes to reflect that, but they don't even have the ones that should be there, like `tabGravity` and `tabMode`, so I guess it can't be trusted. [There's even an issue about it](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183169).

Comment: I am also thinking same.. at the moment no option (: